# Anylogic, parameter variation error during iteration

Tags: error-handling, parameters, simulation, anylogic

I am trying to run a parameter variation experiment with 3 iterations and 100 replications in Anylogic. I use the same 100 seeds {10, 20, 30, ..., 1000} for every replication using

```
root.getDefaultRandomGenerator().setSeed((long) listOfSeeds.get(getCurrentReplication()));
```

in "before simulation run" java action field in parameter variation properties. I am varying one parameter. For retrieving data after each run I inserted following code in "after simulation run" section

```
replication = getCurrentReplication();
double totalMins = 0;
double totalLoading = 0;
double totalUnloading = 0;
int i = 0;

while(i < root.pickTime.size()){
double x = root.pickTime.getX(i);
if(i+7 < root.pickTime.size()  && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+1) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+2) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+3) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+4) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+5) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+6) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+7)){
double y = root.pickTime.getY(i) + root.pickTime.getY(i+1) + root.pickTime.getY(i+2) + root.pickTime.getY(i+3) +root.pickTime.getY(i+4) +root.pickTime.getY(i+5) +root.pickTime.getY(i+6) +root.pickTime.getY(i+7);
pickTimePV.add(x, y);
i += 8;
continue;}
if(i+6 < root.pickTime.size()  && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+1) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+2) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+3) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+4) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+5) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+6)){
double y = root.pickTime.getY(i) + root.pickTime.getY(i+1) + root.pickTime.getY(i+2) + root.pickTime.getY(i+3) +root.pickTime.getY(i+4) +root.pickTime.getY(i+5) +root.pickTime.getY(i+6);
pickTimePV.add(x, y);
i += 7;
continue;}
if(i+5 < root.pickTime.size()  && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+1) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+2) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+3) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+4) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+5)){
double y = root.pickTime.getY(i) + root.pickTime.getY(i+1) + root.pickTime.getY(i+2) + root.pickTime.getY(i+3) +root.pickTime.getY(i+4) +root.pickTime.getY(i+5);
pickTimePV.add(x, y);
i += 6;
continue;}
if(i+4 < root.pickTime.size() && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+1) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+2) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+3) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+4)){
double y = root.pickTime.getY(i) + root.pickTime.getY(i+1) + root.pickTime.getY(i+2) + root.pickTime.getY(i+3) +root.pickTime.getY(i+4);
pickTimePV.add(x, y);
i += 5;
continue;}
if(i+3 < root.pickTime.size() && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+1) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+2) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+3)){
double y = root.pickTime.getY(i) + root.pickTime.getY(i+1) + root.pickTime.getY(i+2) + root.pickTime.getY(i+3);
pickTimePV.add(x, y);
i += 4;
continue;}
if(i+2 < root.pickTime.size() && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+1) && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+2)){
double y = root.pickTime.getY(i) + root.pickTime.getY(i+1) + root.pickTime.getY(i+2);
pickTimePV.add(x, y);
i += 3;
continue;}
if(i+1 < root.pickTime.size() && x == root.pickTime.getX(i+1)){
double y = root.pickTime.getY(i) + root.pickTime.getY(i+1);
pickTimePV.add(x, y);
i += 2;
continue;}
else{
pickTimePV.add(x, root.pickTime.getY(i));
i++;}}
excelFile.writeDataSet(pickTimePV, 1, 1, 1 + iteration);
pickTimePV.reset();
iteration +=3;
kommiUtilization.add(getCurrentIteration(), root.kommiPool.utilization());
aushilfeUtilization.add(getCurrentIteration(), root.aushilfePop.get(0).timeInState(ResourceUsageState.USAGE_BUSY, MINUTE) / (root.kommissionierer.get(0).timeInState(ResourceUsageState.USAGE_BUSY, MINUTE)/root.kommiPool.utilization()));
ordersInQueue.add(getCurrentIteration(), root.orderQueue.size());

for(int j = 0; j < root.loadingTime.size(); j++){
totalLoading += root.loadingTime.getY(j);}
loadingTimePV.add(getCurrentIteration(), totalLoading/root.totalLoadTrucks);
for(int k = 0; k < root.unloadingTime.size(); k++){
totalUnloading += root.unloadingTime.getY(k);}
unloadingTimePV.add(getCurrentIteration(), totalUnloading/root.totalUnloadTrucks);
for(int t = 0; t < root.pickTime.size(); t++){
totalMins += root.pickTime.getY(t);}
totalPickTime.add(getCurrentIteration(), totalMins);
totalLoadTrucksPV.add(getCurrentIteration(), root.totalLoadTrucks);
totalUnloadTrucksPV.add(getCurrentIteration(), root.totalUnloadTrucks);
```

After replication No. 61 (183 simulation runs) the system throws the error:

```
Error in the model during iteration 3
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in the model during iteration 3
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentParamVariation$b.i(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.n$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

Before the error occurs, the last simulation run finishes succesfully (visibile using traceln()). I checked all possible parameter configurations and seed numbers where the error could be thrown with simulation experiments, but everything works fine for simulation experiments. So I guess the error has to do something with the parameter variation experiment setup.
Do you have any ideas how to fix the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try running sequential (disable parallel runs in the exp settings). Maybe that helps...

Comment: Please flag that as "helpful" then, easier for future users to find the reply :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my reputation is too low to upvote your comment..